# How to change the image from the google search result of my website?

Tags: html, image

[here’s the google search image I’m referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNPlX.png)

Can I change that toothbrush image to a different one? Or remove it entirely?

Also, my favicon is a different image, and has been for about a week. How can I change that in the search results?

I tried looking for ways to change the image but no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Google will (typically) use the `og:image` Open Graph tag. See https://ogp.me/.

Comment: Huh, I do have that tag already but with a different image. Maybe it takes some time for Google to update it?

Comment: Yes, it takes some time for Google to reindex. See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/ask-google-to-recrawl to speed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these in `head` tag to specify the data in google search engine

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Your Image URL" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description " />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website, Inc." />
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yea I have those tags but with a different image linked in the content. Maybe it takes time for Google to update it? It’s been a few days though.

Comment: Yeah !! It takes some time . If the answer helps, Please mark it as accepted answer :)